# How can I add labels in specific cells of a GridLayout Panel in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, grid-layout

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        ImageIcon grassIcon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Pamvotis\\Desktop\\Project\\img\\icon.png"); 
        JLabel labels = new JLabel();

        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++) {
                gbc.gridx = col;
                gbc.gridy = row;

                CellPane cellPane = new CellPane();
                Border border = null;
                if (row < 9) {
                    if (col < 5) {
                        border = new MatteBorder(1, 1, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
                    } else {
                        border = new MatteBorder(1, 1, 0, 1, Color.BLACK);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (col < 5) {
                        border = new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 0, Color.BLACK);
                    } else {
                        border = new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK);
                    }
                }
                cellPane.setBorder(border);
                if ((row==0)&&((col==2)||(col==3))) { 
                    cellPane.setBackground(Color.RED);
                } else if ((row==9)&&((col==2)||(col==3))) { 
                    cellPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    labels = new JLabel(grassIcon);add(labels);
                } else {
                    cellPane.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                }

                add(cellPane, gbc);
            }
        }
    }
```

So I have this code but the problem is every time I run the program the labels with the images are placed in the first line after the grid. It happens with every other try I've made the labels always appear on the first line of the grid or on the first line after the grid. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add(labels);
```

You are trying to add the labels to the panel without specifying the constraints. I believe default constraints will be used (whatever they are).

If you want to control the location of components then you need to specify the constraint with every add(...) statement.

Edit:

```
else if ((row==9)&&((col==2)||(col==3))) {cellPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);labels = new JLabel(grassIcon);add(labels);}
```

I'm guessing you want:

```
else if ((row==9)&&((col==2)||(col==3))) 
{
    cellPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    labels = new JLabel(grassIcon);
    //add(labels);
    cellPane.add(labels);
}
else
```

Now you just need to make sure that "cellPane" uses a layout manager.

Comment: so how exactly should I specify the constraint in the add(...) statement ? sorry I am very new at java

Comment: @helpme, I don't know what your requirement is. I have no idea why you are trying to add two components to the grid in the same loop. Maybe you want to add the label to the CellPane, not the panel? Again I have no idea what a CellPane is or what layout manager you are using on the cell pane. `I am very new at java` - Keep a reference to the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) handly. It has working examples of all the Swing basics. There is a section on `Layout Managers` with working examples, if my simple suggestion doesn't help you.

Comment: Also, don't write blocks of code on a single line. Each Java statement should be on its own line to make it more readable and easy to maintain. See edit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time your edit worked!! (CellPane was basically a JPanel I had made)